# Assign a yet unassigned ID to a new entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

We're trying to set up a shadow copy system for auditing some of the tables in our projects database. For Any change (Add, Update, Delete) a copy of that record get's saved to it's shadow table (we're using the term Version).

If we have a table called Profiles with columns (int)ProfileId, (varchar(50))Name, (date)UpdateDate, etc... we would have another table called ProfilesVersion with columns (int)ProfileVersionId, (int)ProfileId, (varchar(50))Name, (date)UpdateDate, etc...

I'm working on the system to make the copies. In the past I have used triggers in the database to catch Insert, Update, Delete. But now we're trying to do it using Entity Framework and Linq.

I can override the SaveChanges on DbContext, and get a second copy into the Version table. However, the key Id that get's populated on the first table does not end up in the Version table.

With Entity Framework, you can have two inserts to the database with data from one entity getting applied to the second. For instance:

```
var res = new Resource{
    SomeValue = someParameter
};
_db.Resource.Add(res);

var newProfile = new Profile{
    ProfileValue = anotherParameter, 
    ForeignResourceId = res.ResourceId // ResourceId is autogenerated
};

_db.Profile.Add(newProfile);
_db.SaveChanges();

var forResourceId = newProfile.ForeignResourceId;
```

Since Profile.ForeignResourceId and Resource.ResourceId are mapped in the model, the newProfile object has the ForeignResourceId that was assigned by the database after SaveChanges(). Somehow entity framework knows to put res.ResourceId into ForeignResourceId once it has been generated from the database.

My code which dynamically copies values from one entity into the Version table does not do that. It simply copies data from the first entity into the new record for the Version entity, but doesn't setup the relationship to populate the key field with the foreign key.

```
public int SaveChanges(Guid userId)
{
    // ... some other code

    // entityEntry is DbEntityEntry, the entity with changes we want to replicate

    // Create audit entity.
    DbSet set = this.Set(auditTypeInfo.AuditEntityType);
    IAuditEntity auditEntity = set.Create() as IAuditEntity;
    set.Add(auditEntity);

    // Copy the properties.
    DbEntityEntry auditEntityEntry = this.Entry(auditEntity);
    foreach (string propertyName in auditTypeInfo.AuditProperties)
    {
        // This copies just the raw value, if any
        auditEntityEntry.Property(propertyName).CurrentValue = entityEntry.Property(propertyName).CurrentValue; 
    }

    // ... 

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

So, following with our example, if we add a Profile record, it get's it's ProfileId, but the ProfileVersion record does not.

How in the above code can I have entity framework set that value in the 'auditentity' that we are copying to?

Comment: If `Resource` has an auto-generated key value the above code won't work either: `res.ResourceId` will be zero when you assign it to `ForeignResourceId`. The audit entity should have a navigation property referring to the source entity, not a primitive FK property.

Comment: I think because the relationship is mapped in the models is why that does work. However, I believe what you said about navigation property is correct. How can I dynamically set that?

Comment: I think you can only do that if your classes have a base class. The audit entity could have a navigation property of the base type.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you case correctly, then:

This will have to do with properties for your entity. If you entity has property (which, I suppose, is a key for you entity) has `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` (assigned at `OnModelCreating`), which translates to `IDENTITY (1,1)` at sql level, there's nothing you can do, because all of that is being handled at database, not ORM level.

What you could do in this case, use `IDENTITY_INSERT`, which would allow you to assign Ids, but, it means that you would also have to generate Ids manually.

In short - get rid of automatic identity generation.

Comment: Clarified what I'm looking for.